# What's the least difference in latitude on a flight between a pair of IATA airports?

Tags: airports, factoids, landmarks, geography

I flew from CBR - Canberra [35.2809° S, 149.1300° E] to ADL - Adelaide [34.9285° S, 138.6007° E] on Tuesday and noticed on the inflight map that it was very close to being perfectly west.  As you can see from the lat/long pairs, it's not far off.

I was wondering if there were other airports closer to 'straight' east-west **that actually have flights between them?**

To clarify, the difference between Canberra and Adelaide is 0.3524 deg latitude.  The 'straightest east-west (or west-east) would have the smallest difference in degrees latitude.

To avoid same-city airports or terminals, the pair should be at least 50km apart.

Partner question: [What's the straightest north-south flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/106732/101)

Comment: Openflights.org has a [database](https://openflights.org/data.html) of airports with latitude and longitude, so one could easily find the closest pair among their data. Of course, this probably includes lots of tiny airports with little or no service, so maybe you want some criteria as to which airports should count.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks, and as from other comments on the other question, I've adjusted to IATA airports in different cities.

Comment: This isn't really very meaningful since shorter routes will be dominated by ATC routing requirements and longer routes will be dominated by great circle routes. Unless your endpoints are on the equator neither will appear straight on any popular projection.

Comment: Openflights also has a database of routes (last updated in February, it appears).  So this might be a fun SQL exercise for somebody with a little more spare time than me.

Comment: As others have pointed out there are two different questions and it's not completely clear which one you're asking. Do you want a pair of cities such that the flight between them travels along the same latitude (this is the question in the title and forces us to look either for very short flights or for flights close to the equator) or a pair of cities with flights between them which lie on the same latitude (this appears to be the question you want to ask from the question body)? In the second case, just by looking at a map: Vienna-Munich, Berlin Schönefeld-Amsterdam-Warsaw, Prague-Krakow.

Comment: @martin.koeberl ah, I'd not considered the 'travels' along - planes could deviate etc. I was wondering more where the pair of cities are closest.  That's what I specify in my calculation example.

Comment: Maybe then a title like _What pair of IATA airports with flights between them has the least difference in latitude?_ would be a better fitting title? (The current title will generate more clicks most likely, and I agree, the one suggested sounds very complicated but there might be a more informative title which doesn't sound too bad)

Comment: @martin.koeberl yeah, hard to word without being...word. I'll give it a try.

Comment: If you want east-west longitude as bonus content, I know a good answer.  DEN Denver International Airport is 104.6737 W, YQR Regina International Airport 104.6558 W.  Granted, east-west degrees are smaller at our latitudes, but it's still pretty darn close!

Comment: @JimMacKenzie you might be interested in posting that on [the related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/106732/whats-the-least-difference-in-longitude-on-a-flight-between-a-pair-of-iata-airp)

Comment: @MarkMayo I found that question later, and did so.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Following the same procedure as the longitude question and the same elimination of nonsense and duplicates:

> SELECT ST_Y(source_geom) as src_y, ST_Y(destination_geom) as dst_y, abs(ST_Y(source_geom)-ST_Y(destination_geom)) as delta, name, destination_airport, source_airport from flights order by delta limit 25;
>
> '35.4213981628418','35.4213981628','4.17941237174091e-11','Olympic Airlines','KSJ','AOK'
>   '43.3021011352539','43.3011016845703','0.00099945068359375','Iberia Airlines','BIO','LCG'
>   '59.3502998352','59.3516998291','0.00139999390000867','Linhas A','PPW','WRY'
>   '32.89860153','32.896800994873','0.00180053512695366','American Airlines','DFW','CHS'
>   '-0.894','-0.891833007335663','0.00216699266433718','Garuda Indonesia','MKW','SOQ'

Our first result, between [Kasos Island Public Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasos_Island_Public_Airport) and [Karpathos Island National Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karpathos_Island_National_Airport), two Greek islands, is shockingly, incredibly straight, but the airports are [only 22km](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=KSJ-AOK&DU=km&SU=mph) apart, failing the distance test.

Excluding that gives us a new candidate: flights between [Bilbao Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilbao_Airport) and [A Coruña Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Coru%C3%B1a_Airport) in northern Spain, a [distance of 444km](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=bio-lcg&DU=km&SU=mph) and a difference in latitude of just .001. However, nobody seems to be operating that route at present. [FlightAware](https://flightaware.com/) and [FlightRadar24](https://www.flightradar24.com) list no such flights, and the OneWorld route map shows only an Iberia flight from A Coruña to Madrid.

Next is PPW-WRY in Scotland, home to the [shortest scheduled passenger flight in the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westray_to_Papa_Westray_flight). Certainly fun, but less than 3km.

Which brings us to our actual winner: [Dallas/Fort Worth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dallas/Fort_Worth_International_Airport)-[Charleston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charleston_International_Airport), United States. This provides an impressive [distance of 1,589km](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=dfw-chs&DU=km&SU=mph) between the two US cities with a latitude difference of 0.0018. The route is served by twice-daily nonstops on American Airlines, [AAL2762](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/AAL2762/history/20171215/0100Z/KDFW/KCHS)/[AAL2763](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/AAL2763/history/20171214/1300Z/KCHS/KDFW)/[AAL2764](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/AAL2764/history/20171214/1700Z/KDFW/KCHS) (for whatever reason, 2764 is used for both directions).

**Update**: Going by azimuth, [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) tells me the winner is [TAS-UGC](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=tas-ugc), a bearing of 90.007, assuming WGS84 geography.

Comment: You should also calculate the azimuth for this one :)

Comment: This is the sort of one I wanted - DFW to Charleston - that's awesome - basically directly east!

Comment: Hmm, re TAS-UGC....back to Uzbekistan!!

Comment: The azimuth answer depends on the direction of flight as it assumes a great circle flight so the bearing changes during flight (except if you are at the equator). Perhaps better to divide latitude delta by distance to get a sense of "how close to due west" you are.